# How to add query 'greater than' date in match aggregation query in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, date, match

I need add date from to get response from mongo match.

my schema in db:

```
schedule: {
  creationDate: "2020-12-06T00:48:38.000Z",
  creationUser: "5fcc23936ce8678e43d35b06",
  end: "2020-12-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  operationType: "C",
  start: "2020-12-05T20:00:00.000Z",
  _id: "5fcc2a664d18280025ac0acb"
}
```

my query:

```
Object.keys(params.filter).map((key) => {
  if(key === 'start') {
    match[key] = {
      $gte: new Date(params.filter[key])
    }
  }
})
```

my result:

```
[]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to proivide help you need to share some more details: What is this `params` object and where (inside which component) do you do the transformation, what is it's state before the iteration of the keys where does it come from? Help us with litle debugging efforts on your side.

Comment: @KiaKaha
Thanks, below, I apply the solution found in mongo atlas.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the query. what I needed to do was create an aggregate for a match in mongodb, which can bring dates greater than the one entered by the user. Only CLI samples appear in the mongo documentation. So I came here for help. But I found the answer by creating the query in the constructor that mongo atlas provides. Here I share it. I love you so much.

```
"creationDate": {
    "$gte": {
      "$date": "2020-12-01T03:00:00Z"
    },
    "$lte": {
      "$date": "2020-12-31T03:00:00Z"
    }
  }
```

Translated to my code specifically, the solution is this way:

```
Object.keys(params.filter).map((key) => {
  if(key === 'employee') {
    match[key] = {
      $oid: params.filter[key]
    }
  }
  if(key === 'start') {
    match[key] = {
      $gte: {
        $date: params.filter[key]
      }
    }
  }
})
```